# Solr - Grouping Result giving wrong count

Tags: solr

I am using Solr Grouping result. But it behaves wrong.

[image]

I grouped on the base of email field. In my database i have 2 rows for the email address "ashhaf63@hotmail.com" but SOLR showing 7147 numFound which is of course wrong, it should be 2.

When i try to search with particular email address like "ashhaf63@hotmail.com" with grouping then it shows perfect result and it shows 2 in the numFound attribute which is correct.

[image]

I believe that, it is because of field type in my Solr schema, i was using text field type in start but i have changed it to my own field type now. I have defined my own field type and using my own field type now.

[image]

[image]

After using my own field type, i am facing same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your grouping response, you will see it matched 7147 documents because the group consists of all emails that have "hotmail" in their address `<str name="groupValue">hotmail</str>` and not the entire email address. This behavior is because you are expecting the values in the fields to be indexed as complete strings, like "ashhaf63@hotmail.com", but from the definition of your `email` fieldType you are doing some tokenizing of the field values. That is resulting in multiple indexed values for that field. Specifically the [StandardTokenizerFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StandardTokenizerFactory) that splits a value on all non alphanumeric characters. So that same email address is being indexed as three separate values, "ashhaf63", "hotmail" and "com".

Because of this, I would recommend creating a new field that uses a simple string fieldType like the following:

```
<!-- The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim. -->
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
```

Then create a new field like this:

```
<field name="emailaddress" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
```

Then perform your grouping on this new `emailaddress` field, which will group on the entire email address value.